# An idiom likely having a more figurative translation

Tags: grammar, translation, idiom

There is a very nice German song whose name is, *[Ich lass mich auf den Sommer ein](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qts-RxyrO9s)*.

I have found the following idiom with *einlassen*: *sich auf etw (accusative) einlassen*, which is rendered as *to get involved in sth*.

So, according to this dictionary translation, the name of the song should be, *I'm getting involved in the summer*.

But this translation, though probably grammatically correct, seems to convey neither the exact meaning of the song's title, nor its spirit, for that matter.

So I've come up with the more natural-sounding English translation of *I'm into the summer*.

Is this version correct?

Comment: About your Youtube link: "Unfortunately, this SME-music-content is not available in Germany because GEMA has not granted the respective music publishing rights."

Comment: According to my dictionary, **sich einlassen** can mean **to embark**, which, if you think about it, makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

As @bouscher's comment hints, the answer is no. Now you're saying pretty much the opposite of the original text.

How about:

> I'm giving summer a chance.

Comment: Could be _I'm giving summer a chance_. However, I have seen no expression with _einlassen_ having the meaning of _to give sth a chance_.

Comment: @indoxica: it is not a literal translation but *"sich einlassen"* is very close to *"to give sth/so a chance"*.